# Binary Linear Error Correcting Codes meeting the Griesmer Bound

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

The Griesmer Bound on linear ECC's of parameters [m,k,d,q] states that:

$$m \geq \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \operatorname{ceil}\left(\frac{d}{q^{i}}\right)$$

I need to show that binary linear codes meeting equality on this bound have a basis made of d-weight code words. I need some sort of direction because i'm pretty much stuck on this one. Thanks

Comment: There is an interesting question lying under all this. Before we get into that I need to remind you to check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). At least superficially this may look like an attempt to outsource a homework, and therefore may attract negative attention. That guide gives you pointers in how to avoid such.

Comment: Anyway, the Griesmer bound is proven recursively, by induction on $k$. It is natural to think that this claim can be handled similarly. Have you done the case $k=1$? What about $k=2$? What about $k=q, q=2$, i.e. 2-dimensional binary codes?